# Intro activity is too slow to close

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a intro Activity that contains a View Pager to do a sliding intro page, like the picture above [intro activity with slides](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucsFg.png)

I have three slides and, in the third slide, I have a button "DONE" that close the activity and redirect the app to a login page.

My problem is that when I click in done, the activity is too slow for close. Can someone help me?

Here is my code:

```
[Activity (NoHistory = true, MainLauncher = true)]
public class IntroView : FragmentActivity
{
    private ViewPager _viewPager;
    private ControleExibicaoIntro _controleExibicaoIntro;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        _controleExibicaoIntro = new ControleExibicaoIntro(this);

        if (!_controleExibicaoIntro.DeveExibirIntro())
        {
            FechaApresentacao();
        }

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.IntroView);

        _viewPager = FindViewById<ViewPager>(Resource.Id.ViewPager);
        _viewPager.Adapter = new IntroAdapter(SupportFragmentManager);

        _viewPager.AddOnPageChangeListener(new IntroIndicator(this.Window));
        _viewPager.SetPageTransformer(false, new IntroPageTransformer());
        ActionBar.Hide();

        var btnNext = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnNext);
        btnNext.Click += BtnNext_Click;

        var btnSkip = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnSkip);
        btnSkip.Click += BtnSkip_Click;
    }

    private void BtnSkip_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FechaApresentacao();
    }

    private void BtnNext_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_viewPager.CurrentItem == (_viewPager.Adapter.Count - 1))
        {
            FechaApresentacao();
        }
        else
        {
            _viewPager.CurrentItem++;
        }

    }

    private void FechaApresentacao()
    {
        //_controleExibicaoIntro.CancelaExibicaoIntro();

        var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(SettingsView));
        OverridePendingTransition(0, 0);

        StartActivity(intent);
        OverridePendingTransition(0, 0);

        Finish();
    }
}
```

FechaApresentacao() is the method that I use to close the intro activity and redirect to other activity.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding it after you call Finish() or the second option which will close all activities other than the one you are starting.

```
private void FechaApresentacao(){
    //_controleExibicaoIntro.CancelaExibicaoIntro();
    var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(SettingsView));
    StartActivity(intent);
    Finish();
    OverridePendingTransition(0, 0);
}


private void FechaApresentacao(){
    //_controleExibicaoIntro.CancelaExibicaoIntro();
    var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(SettingsView));
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    StartActivity(intent);
    OverridePendingTransition(0, 0);
}
```